# JavaScript is setting variables for partial to be appended before Rails actually sets them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form which I use to create a list. I want to give the user the ability to create new forms for new items to be saved for future list making. I want to have a "+" button to add create a new form via JavaScript. It was working great on my test user, but things were getting cluttered so I made a new user to start fresh. When I tried to load my new list page I get his with this:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Specifically, it's pointing to this bit in my JavaScript:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(1)').append("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'shared/user_item_form', locals: {f: @f, category_id: @category.id} %>");
```

I need to pass these variables to any new form that's going to be rendered, but these variables rely on data that is passed from the server or database or something. It seems like it's trying to run my JavaScript first, despite me declaring `$(document).ready`.

Here is the form in it's entirety.

Line 26 is where this problem starts, where I declared some class variables in order for them to reach my javascript down below.

Line 43 is where I render the first partial, the same one that will be duplicated when the user presses "+". When the user presses that button I want the same exact form to pop up underneath it.

https://pastebin.com/ieLYfYm4

I'm a real noob when it comes to combining JS and Rails, and I've been struggling a lot with this part of my project. I don't really understand what gets loaded first or where my JS is supposed to go. What I have hacked together seems to work fine though until now. Not sure why it was even working at any point if this now a problem. Maybe my browser stored something in the cache that was preventing this error from being raised?

Code if you can't look at the pastbin

```
<div class="new-list">
    <h2>New List</h2>
    <%= form_for @list, url: list_path, html: {class: "form-signin"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name your list (optional)" %>
        <!-- Category -->
        <div class="categories">
            <% current_user.categories.each do |category| %>
                <h3 class="category">
                  <%= category.name %>
                </h3>
                <!-- Items -->  
                <div class="dropdown-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<%= category.name %>">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- Dropdown div -->
                <div id="<%= category.name %>" class="collapse">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <!-- User Item table -->
                        <table class="items">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Add</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Qnty</th>
                            </tr>
                        <% category.user_items.each do |item| %>
                            <%= f.fields_for l = @list.list_items.build, index: l.id do |list_item| %>
                                <% @category = category %>
                                <% @f = f %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= list_item.check_box :user_item_id, { checked: false }, item.id, nil %></td>
                                    <td><%= item.name %></td>
                                    <td><%= item.price %></td>
                                    <td><%= list_item.number_field :quantity,
                                                                                                    min: 1,
                                                                                                    class: "num"%></td>
                                </tr>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Create a new item here:</h3>
                    <%= render partial: 'shared/user_item_form', locals: {f: f, category_id: category.id}  %>
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="add-item"></span>Add More</h4>
                </div>
            <% end %> <!-- current_user.categories -->
            <br>
            <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<!-- dropdown button script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.data-toggle').collapse();
      addNewItemForm();
  });

function addNewItemForm(){
  $('#add-item').click(function(){
        $(this).parents(':eq(1)').append("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'shared/user_item_form', locals: {f: @f, category_id: @category.id} %>");
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The error tells you that `@category` is `nil`; where are you setting that variable? It must be set in the controller action related to the view. Can you show the controller code? But please add the code as text (not an image or link) in your question.

Comment: added the code to the original question. I set @category about halfway down in a nested form

Comment: Double check the value of `category.user_items`, it seems to be `nil` which causes `@category` to be `nil` as well.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right, and this might be a symptom of a deeper but where my User callback (which creates default_categories) is no longer working after my database reset...no idea what's causing this, but thanks.

Comment: I take that back. While my default_categories callback has a minor bug (which I figured out) this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the javascript function addNewItemForm() at the bottom of your script is evaluated not when you invoke it, but when the page is fully rendered at first, and at that moment and at that place, when Rails tries to evaluate the following string:`<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'shared/user_item_form', locals: {f: @f, category_id: @category.id} %>` the @category variable is out of scope and undefined.

Actually, you need to make another server request on click of a button with corresponding params and let the server to do the work: render new partial and invoke javascript to alter HTML.

You can do that easily with the following example:

> `<%= link_to 'Add New Item', [:new, category, :items], remote: true %>`

("remote: true" will make an ajax request).

You will get category in URL params in your controller and can instantiate it again:

> `@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])`

and then respond with the following code (new.js.erb):

> `<%= j render 'shared/user_item_form', category_id: @category.id %>`

(which is simply a shorthand of your line)

Here is the reference to documentation with similar example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example

Comment: Ok, I'm just still confused about where to stick this line after I've sent the request and got the category from the controller

<%= j render 'shared/user_item_form', category_id: @category.id %>

Do I render it from the controller?

Comment: Also, you know know how I could pass my form_builder through params? I can pass it but it's turned into a string. When I try to constantize it, I get an error:

'NameError Exception: wrong constant name #<ActionView'

Comment: Figured out my first question. For those who don't know, you create a file called new.js.erb in your controller's view directory and place your javascript there. It will automatically be called/rendered by the controller.


I decided to open up another question for my second issue as my initial problem has been solved. Your solution worked,  thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't pass FormBuilder object through request params, but you can pass your List ID (using routes or just adding to link_to params), then instantiate List in the controller on Ajax request `@list = List.find(params[:list_id])`, and pass down to view and partial: `<%= j render 'shared/user_item_form', category_id: @category.id, list: @list %>`. And inside the partial wrap everything in `<%= fields_for @list do |f| %>...<%= end %>` – that will give you the same behaviour as passing the FormBuilder itself into partial.

Comment: Thanks, only problem is since the list hasn't been saved yet the ID is nil

Comment: If the list is a new record (you can check if params[:list_id]), just instantiate it as List.new – that will give you nice list[field_name] attribute names using `fields_for` in your partial and you can use your partial inside the initial `form_for` block. And if the list is an existing record, then `fields_for` will populate the input values for you, so that will give you a universal solution :)

Comment: Ok so I instantiated a new list and passed it to my partial. In my partial I set it up like

`<%= fields_for @list do |f| %>`

  `<%= f.fields_for @list.item.build |item| %>`

    `...`

  `<%end%>`

`<%end%>`

And sweet baby jesus it worked! Thanks so much man!